# Log out all users with passport and cookie-session

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, session-cookies, cookie-session

I'm lazily changing my user schema (mongoose).   My code will rewrite a user's data when a user logs in and is still using the old schema.

To ensure no user is already logged in with the old schema when the new version gets deployed (which would throw errors), I want to log out all users and delete their user sessions when the app restarts.

I'm using [`passportJS`](http://www.passportjs.org/) and saving the sessions with [`cookie-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session).

```
app.use(cookieParser(env.cookie))
app.use(cookieSession({
  cookie: {maxAge: 60000},
  secret: 'ThisIsASecret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}))

require('./config/passport')(passport)
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most elegant solution, but changing the cookie-session secret string works:

```
app.use(cookieSession({
  cookie: {maxAge: 60000},
  secret: 'ThisHasChanged',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}))
```